# Is blocking within a future still blocking?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, concurrency, blocking, future

Blocking bad, async good, but is blocking within a future still blocking? This is something that I keep coming back to; consider following pseudo-code:

```
def queryName(id:Id):Future[String]
def queryEveryonesNames:Future[Seq[String]] = {
  val everyonesIds:Future[Seq[Id]] = getIds
  val everyonesNames:Future[Seq[Future[String]]] = {
    everyonesIds.map(seq.map(id=>queryName(id)))
  }
  // I'm trying to understand the impact of what I'll do below
  everyonesNames.map(seq=>seq.map(fut=>blocking(fut, 1 s)))
}
queryEveryonesNames
```

In the last line I turned `Future[Seq[Future[String]]]` (notice **future** within **future**) into `Future[Seq[String]]` by **blocking** on the **inner future**.

Blocking on a future within a future feels redundant, at least here, yet having a future within a future feels redundant as well.

Can you propose a smarter way of getting rid of the inner future?

Do you think blocking on a future inside a future is bad? If so why and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, future blocking is blocking, you should avoid that, as resources will be blocked to wait for a result, even if they are in another thread.
If I understood correctly, your question is how to convert `Future[Seq[Future[String]]]` into `Future[Seq[String]]` in a non-blocking way.

You can do that with for-comprehensions:

```
val in =  Future[Seq[Future[String]]]
val m = for( a <- in ) // a is Seq[Future[String]]
yield ( Future.sequence(a)) // yields m = Future[Future[Seq[String]]]
val result = for(a <- m; b <- a) yield (b) // yields Future[Seq[String]]
```

**EDIT:**
Or just:

```
val result = in.flatMap(a => Future.sequence(a))
```

Comment: You should get the same result with just `in.flatMap( Future.sequence )`

Comment: The `Future` companion object has some very useful methods, thanks for introducing it. Cheers!